# iOSApplication product type for Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm following this tutorial from Apple ([link)](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/capturingphotos-camerapreview) and noticed that the sample project is a `.swiftpm` file which imports into Xcode 15 Beta. I haven't tried on Xcode 14 yet.

While inspecting the `Package.swift` file, I came across a new product type `iOSApplication`:

```
.iOSApplication(
    name: "Capturing Photos",
    targets: ["App"],
    teamIdentifier: "XXX",
    displayVersion: "1.0",
    bundleVersion: "1",
    appIcon: .asset("AppIcon"),
    supportedDeviceFamilies: [
        .pad,
        .phone
    ],
    supportedInterfaceOrientations: [

    ],
    capabilities: [
        .camera(purposeString: "This sample app uses the camera."),
        .photoLibrary(purposeString: "This sample app uses your photo library.")
    ]
)
```

which appears to be a full replacement for `xcodeproj` files. I can't find any mentions of this in the SPM documentation. The project also has a new Swift logo icon at the root compared to the blue icon for xcodeproj.

I'm also able to build and deploy this project for my iPhone device.

Has this been announced anywhere? Is there more information on the supported features/API (autocomplete is no help)? It doesn't appear as an option yet within the Xcode 15 project wizard, but presumably we can start using this now?

Comment: Maybe it was made for Swift Playgrounds? It's also working with Xcode 14.

Comment: Yea it appears related to Playgrounds support (according to Twitter replies) although still very odd there is no documentation to be found.